# Would the existence of Planet Nine rule out the possibility of a sixth giant planet?

Tags: solar-system, gas-giants, 9th-planet

I'm aware that there have been attempts to simulate the evolution of the Solar System with *six* giant planets<sup>1</sup>, as opposed to the traditional four or five. The recent proposed Planet Nine would probably invalidate some of those models, although I don't know how drastic its effects would be.

Would Planet Nine fit into models with six giant planets? Have any simulations been done that support such a  scenario?

---

<sup>1 The models I'm most familiar with were created by [Nesvorny & Morbidelli (2012)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.2957).</sup>